# Ежемесячный прогресс сообщества

Tags: обсуждение

Наше сообщество Stack Overflow на русском активно развивается и, что на мой взгляд более важно, постоянно пополняется новыми увлеченными знатоками программирования.  Далеко не всегда участники сообщества успевают уследить за всем, что происходит вокруг. Возможным решением может быть создание своеобразного бюллетеня прогресса, в котором будут отражены интересные события произошедшие за месяц и подчеркнут статус важных показателей.

#### Что будет в бюллетене?

На мой взгляд, в бюллетене должна быть прежде всего интересная сообществу информация. С нетерпением жду ваших предложений в ответах к этой публикации. Все же, со своей стороны спешу предположить, что следующие разделы будут интересны.

**Основные показатели**

- Сколько людей получило реальную помощь?

  - Количество вопросов.
  - Количество ответов.
  - Количество принятых ответов.
  - Количество ответов получивших голос против.
- Скольким людям мы помогли?

  - Количество уникальных пользователей, посетивших сайт.

**Ценности**

- Вклад нашего сообщества в развитие индустрии в целом (например, ссылки на выступления кого-либо из сообщества на конференциях).
- Ценность базы знаний `[требует обсуждения]`.
- Каким опытом мы обладаем `[требует обсуждения]`.

**Лучшее сообщества**

- Лучшее на Мете.

  - Публикация с наибольшим количеством ответов.
  - Публикация с наибольшим количеством голосов «за».
  - Публикация получившая наибольшее количество просмотров.
- Лучшие вопросы.

  - *Точно так же как и на Мете*.
- Лучшие ответы.

  - Набравший наибольшее количество голосов.
  - Самый «быстрый» принятый ответ.
  - Самый развернутый ответ.

**Компания сообществу**

- Список исправленных дефектов.
- Список нововведений.
- Ссылки на посты с последними новостями (о компании, о сообществах, о движке).

**Дополнительно** `[требует обсуждения]`

- Ссылки на лучшие статьи на других сайтах про сообщества и их аналитика.
- Выводы. Рекомендации и пожелания на будущий месяц.

---

Составлять и публиковать бюллетень берусь я. Любой участник сообщества может оставить комментарий к бюллетеню с пожеланиями того, что он/она хочет увидеть/более не видеть в «следующем номере». В дополнении, в течении месяца можно присылать мне на почту любые пожелания и отзывы.

Буду рад выслушать ваши мысли, идеи и пожелания по формату в ответах к этой публикации.

Comment: Думаю, обратную связь можно будет давать, когда мы увидим первый выпуск бюллетеня.

Comment: А вы эту идею заморозили или это всё-таки будет в ближайшее время реализовано?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Результаты первой публикации получились достаточно неоднозначными. Возможно, стоит возобновить. Недавно, хотел это сделать немного в другом формате: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3694/ Но также как и в первом случае, не понятен результат (интересно/не интересно).